# How can I add loading effect on top of my slider using jQuery

Tags: jquery, loading, effect

How can I add loading effect on top of my slider using jQuery [like on this site](http://wooexpert.com/).

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing that requires a loading effect. Does it give periodic updates on its level of progress?

Comment: That site is using the jQuery Revolution Slider, fyi. You can keep track of the timer (to load the next frame) and base the width of a div on this formula: 100% / time in ms. Then you'll have to align it to the top. That can be achieved by using positions and transform elements in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Owl Carousel. Look at this link: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/progressBar.html